# Deconstructors and nullable reference types

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types, deconstructor

I have a class with the deconstructor:

```
public void Deconstruct(out bool isSuccess, out TSuccess? value, out Error? error) {...}
```

Value of `isSuccess` defines whish of `value` or `error` is null.

Can I somehow let compiler know about this, so when I call:

```
var (isSuccess, value, error) = result;
```

analyzer knows which variable can and cannot be null?

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge you can't.

The [`NotNullWhenAttribute`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/) postcondition relies on the boolean return value. For example:

```
bool TryExecute(
    [NotNullWhen(true)] out TSuccess? value, 
    [NotNullWhen(false)] out Error? error)
```

Since [deconstructor must be defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct#user-defined-types) in the way that its return type is `void`, you can't mix the two techniques.